# Readonly admin user in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

we have a postgres database we want to run a number of checks against.  Part of the tool involves looping over database all the database tables and views, checking grants and other things - so it would be entirely pointless if we had to grant access to this user to individual tables.

We want to be able to create a user that has full read privileges to *anything*, regardless of what permissions are set in the database - like a db owner - but has no write access at all.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Do you need this user to read the data in the tables? Or is checking the metadata (permissions, ...) enough?

Comment: we need to read counts and definitions of views and stuff.  Some validations also read the data in the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is granting the `SELECT` privilege on every individual object that needs to be examined.  You can make the work easier with

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES/SEQUENCES/... IN SCHEMA ... TO ...;
```

You can also use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` to set the permissions on future objects.

I recommend that you create a `readonly` role and do all that once. Then you can create a read-only user by making the user a member of that role.

Answer (score 1):

With postgresql 14 you can just do:

```
GRANT pg_read_all_data TO my_role;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/predefined-roles.html